# Cordova Windows Phone 8.1 play local video file

Tags: html, cordova, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently testing an App on Windows Phone 8.1, that i have build with Cordova. (Working properly in Android & iOS).

The app contains images and videos, which can be viewed inside the app.
Im playing the videos with the default HTML5 video Tag.

```
<video id="questionVideo" class="videoClass" src="path to video" type="video/mp4" poster="path to poster" webkit-playsinline></video>
```

I have the following issue:
Local videos do not start at all. If I'm replacing the local video path to an external video (http://...) the video is playing fine.

(We had the same issue with Android, where we had to stream the video with a local webserver into the app... please dont tell me, i have to do the same for windows...)

PS: In Windows Phone 8.0 the video is working correctly (but playing in an external video player and not inline -> known issue).

Comment: Please how did you fix it?

Comment: @eeadev i didn't .. we froze that part of our project

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck getting local video playback to work on a Windows 8.1 Tablet using JWplayer v6.

Haven't been able to get it to go fullscreen, but maybe that's not a need for you on the phone.

http://www.jwplayer.com